# Mac gets very hot when locked and on battery power

Tags: sleep-wake, power

Mac seems to use alot of CPU power and gets hot when on lock screen/sleeping, and on battery power. I i "forget" to pull the power over night and come back to the mac in the morning, its very hot, which means it just has wasted alot of energy for no good. What's a good way of debugging this and how to fix it? I really don't want the mac to waste power when i'm not using it.

Comment: since activity monitor's snapshots are live, not stored with process history, you can use top command to log what is happening behind the scenes. Also there's console.app. And  https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-power-gadget can log temperatures, clock frequency,  power usage etc to a file, but no process details will be there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried an SMC reset? System Management Controller "can resolve certain issues related to power, battery and other features." according to Apple's website.

There are different methods for resetting SMC, depending on your model. Here is a link to Apple's site with instructions for resetting SMC.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295